# How to open a popup iframe in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, iframe, popupwindow

I have a simple page which has a little JS script, which after 5 second I want to open a popup with an external page and I don't know how to implement that. I just want to use this http://www.tweego.nl/jeegoopopup/documentation/v100#properties.

My code where I want to implement popup is this

```
setTimeout(function() {??popup code??; }, 500);
```

I've tried to do it myself but i don't know js..

Regards,

Comment: Show a [jQuery UI dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) and put an iframe in the root div of it.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the only real reason to do this is to provide annoying advertising messages. The browser blocks you from doing it.